# Passenger instance becomes idle, starts chewing up CPU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, cpu

Here's the `passenger-status` output from one of my affected production instances:

```
Version : 4.0.53
Date    : 2015-01-07 00:59:55 +0000
Instance: 6919
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 8
Processes     : 8
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/app/web#default:
  App root: /home/app/web
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 7009    Sessions: 1       Processed: 1607    Uptime: 53m 19s
    CPU: 7%      Memory  : 217M    Last used: 2m 51s ago
  * PID: 7021    Sessions: 1       Processed: 1823    Uptime: 53m 19s
    CPU: 6%      Memory  : 217M    Last used: 2s ago
  * PID: 7032    Sessions: 0       Processed: 2241    Uptime: 53m 19s
    CPU: 7%      Memory  : 218M    Last used: 2s ago
  * PID: 7044    Sessions: 1       Processed: 1539    Uptime: 53m 19s
    CPU: 15%     Memory  : 209M    Last used: 14m 27s ago
  * PID: 7057    Sessions: 0       Processed: 1549    Uptime: 53m 19s
    CPU: 5%      Memory  : 217M    Last used: 1s ago
  * PID: 7074    Sessions: 1       Processed: 554     Uptime: 53m 18s
    CPU: 41%     Memory  : 220M    Last used: 41m 37s ago
  * PID: 7085    Sessions: 1       Processed: 1564    Uptime: 53m 18s
    CPU: 10%     Memory  : 219M    Last used: 7m 5s ago
  * PID: 7106    Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 53m 17s
    CPU: 56%     Memory  : 174M    Last used: 52m 30s ago
```

As you can see, two of the 8 instances have not been used in >40min, and yet they're chewing up most of my machine's CPU. Any tips on how to go about debugging this?

Comment: any loops in your code?

Comment: If an instance gets into this state, does it ever recover from it (after an hour, a day)? Do you have New Relic or a similar tool running, that might give you insights into slow controller actions? Is it possible that this instances might run extrem complex queries on the database, did you have a look into the database's log?

Comment: Good tips! @Rots, yes, there are lots of loops in my code. The codebase is rather large though, so statically inspecting each loop would take too long.

Comment: @spickermann AFAIK, the instance never recovers. I do have New Relic, and all my controller actions run in under 1s. Average response time is 150ms (until all the instances get clogged up, anyway). I don't think there are any extremely complex queries running, but I'll have a look at the DB logs.

Comment: @fedenusy how about writing to a log file on every loop iteration, perhaps a simple number per loop. Then when you get a 56% cpu you might see a lot of 1's, or 2's, to help narrow it down.

Comment: @Rots that doesn't sound like a good idea. With hundreds - thousands of loops in my codebase, it would take a long time to implement. With ~200 requests / minute, the log files would become totally unreadable.

Comment: I am not familiar with Passenger, but I would not be surprised if Passenger writes (or can be configured to write) incomming requests into a logfile. Or you could add a before_filter to your app that does this. Searching for the latest entry for a given PID might help to find a pattern.

Comment: Good idea @spickermann, I'll add PID to my logs. Might help narrow it down.

Comment: @fedenusy The loop idea does sound like a chore with your codebase. If I was debugging the problem on windows i'd take a memory dump and analyze using windbg, perhaps there are similar tools for your OS.